# Receive Email notifications of New Calendar appointments in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, calendar

I have a scheduler assistant that can setup up an Outlook Calendar Appointment on my behalf. Is there a way that I could get an email notification for new scheduled appointments automatically?  Currently I have to  scroll my own calendar to see appointments that are scheduled by an assistant on my be half.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9fdeddb6-1c15-4c74-a73c-b4ee3afb5b47/delegate-notification?forum=exchange2010

Is this the same issue as you? If so, I'm afraid that it is no possible to send a notification to the manager automatically. As a workaround, the assistant could forward the appointment to the manager.